# How to fix the height auto issue in the 2 column layout with background div

Tags: html, css

I had created two column layout with 2 background divisions and applied two different background colors namely green and white and inserted content into it. Iam not getting white background height auto. to get display i need to fix height(in this case height:350x). I want the height to be auto depending on internal elements. Below is the code i tried.

```css
.main {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 40px;
}

.row {
  background-color: white;
  height: 350px;
}

.col1 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.col2 {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1">
      <img src="http://clipart-library.com/images/pcodkzBri.jpg" width="250px">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a responsive type page?

Comment: @vijay, responsive also

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
   background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    display:inline-flex;

}

.col1 {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;

}
img{
  width:100%;
}

.col2 {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    margin:0 auto;

}
```

I think you want somethig like this.Dont forget to remove the `width` property from `<img../>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can use Flex-Box!

Try this style:

```
<style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .main {
        background-color: green;
        padding: 40px;
    }

    .row {
       background-color: white;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
    }

    .col1 {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
    }
    .col1 img {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .col2 {
        flex: 1;
    }
</style>
```

And remove width attribute from `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="http://clipart-library.com/images/pcodkzBri.jpg">
```

Comment: Is was a mistake it just 1 without fr. 1fr normally used with CSS-Grid not flex-box!